# Convert a Cookie to string

Tags: c#, string, cookies, type-conversion

I have a cookie called `LoginCookie` and would like to convert the value to a string. how would I go around converting it?

After converting it to a string, I will put the string's data in a label.

Comment: In a HttpCookie?  It has a .Value property, if not what contains your cookie?

Comment: @AlexK. yes there is a value. I would like to convert the value of the cookie to a string. Yes it is a HttpCookie.

Comment: HttpCookie.Value is a string : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.value(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

As already noted, the `Value` property of `HttpCookie` returns all cookie data as string.

```
var cookie = new HttpCookie("CookieName");
cookie["1"] = "Value1";
cookie["2"] = "Value2";

string defaultValueString = cookie.Value; 
// result: "1=Value1&2=Value2"
```

If the cookie contains multiple keys, the `Values` property lets you access a certain key. You can use this to return a custom format.

```
var valuesByKey = cookie.Values.Keys.Cast<string>()
    .ToDictionary(k => k, v => cookie.Values[v]);

string customValueString = string.Join("; ", 
    valuesByKey.Select(kvp => $"Name: '{kvp.Key}', Value: '{kvp.Value}'");
// result: "Name: '1', Value: 'Value1'; Name: '2', Value: 'Value2'"
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's an HttpCookie, you can simply access its value with its .Value property:

```
// Some cookie
var cookie = new HttpCookie("LoginCookie") { Value = "Hello!" };

// Accessing its value
var cookieValue = cookie.Value;

// Some label
var label = new Label();

// Setting the label text
label.Text = cookieValue;
```

That makes label.Text = "Hello!"

Comment: The cookie "LoginCookie" already has a stored value. how would I go about retrieving it?

Comment: If you want to save it in another variable: string cookieValue = myLoginCookie.Value;